# UIScrollView isn't detect UITouch Events

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, touch

I've a `UIScrollView` with a subview `UIView`, here `UIView` also has subview of type `UIImageView`.

The hierarchy something like `ViewController -> UIScrollView -> UIView -> UIImageView`.

All, `UIScrollView, UIView, UIImageView` added dynamically, all enabled `userInteractionEnabled=YES`, at once SIX views visible on `UIScrollView` as user scrolls the next SIX `UIViews` will be visible.

I am implementing UITouch events to detect any touch on my `UIImageView`

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //I want to detect particular UIImageView
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Here, user can move any UIImageView
}
```

But, I can't detect touch on it. I try for some other ways said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397818/using-uitouch-inside-a-uiscrollview). Also tried some of my mind suggested me, but I found & realize that any subviews under `UIScrollView` couldn't detect any object.

I also tried for one more thing that, I added a `UIView` as subview in `self.view`, any its interesting to know that, its detects `touch`!!

Is anyone with this kind of issue, having any solution? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can do one things,

Same Problem I have already face,So
In UIscrollview Add  Caustom UIButton and set image and define tag all the button into the UIButton.
this way work very smoothly.

```
UIScrollView* scrForSubItem = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,2,1024,580)]; 
[scrForSubItem setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
scrForSubItem.minimumZoomScale = 1;
scrForSubItem.maximumZoomScale = 3;
scrForSubItem.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrForSubItem.pagingEnabled = NO;
scrForSubItem.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
scrForSubItem.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrForSubItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scrForSubItem.delegate = self;

int xOffset = 0;
int yOffset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [currnetitem count]; i++) {


UIImageView* imgViewBtn=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset,yOffset,            246,170)] autorelease];

    [imgViewBtn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imgViewBtn setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    imgViewBtn.image=btnImg;

    UIButton *btnSelectTile = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnSelectTile setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,246,170)];
    [btnSelectTile setTag:i];
    [btnSelectTile setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btnSelectTile addTarget:self action:@selector(scrImagePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imgViewBtn addSubview:btnSelectTile];

    [self.scrForSubItem addSubview:imgViewBtn];
   xOffset += btnSelectTile.frame.size.width+10;

    if(xOffset>scrollWidth)
    {
        xOffset=0;
        yOffset += btnSelectTile.frame.size.height+10;
        [scrForSubItem setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xOffset,yOffset)];
    }
    else{

        [scrForSubItem setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xOffset,170)];

    }

    [self.viewa ddSubview:scrForSubItem];
```

}

Comment: Tarun, have you really checked ! Is it invoking `touch` events?

Comment: Can you please put the entire code? Where you implements `touch` events!

Comment: plz expalin what do u want,after touch or what do u want funcionlity after touch event.

Comment: When user click on any `UIImageView` he'll be able to move that on `UIScrollView`.

Comment: [btnSelectTile addTarget:self action:@selector(scrImagePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; u can use for any action for specific image

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
 //sampleImageView is the imageView.
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:sampleImageView];
 if ([touch view] == sampleImageView) 
  {
    //.....    
  }
}
```

Use this for touch Detection.Check it Hope it helps.Thanks :)

Comment: Nikhil, thanks for response!! But what I asked is, It's doesn't go inside this method! Its not invoking any `touch` method when I touch on `UIScrollView`. So this won't be my answer.

Answer (score 0):

// Create .h file

@interface AppScrollView : UIScrollView {

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@end

// Create .m file

## import "AppScrollView.h"

@implementation AppScrollView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
  {
  if ([super initWithFrame:frame]){
  }
  return self;
  }

  - (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
    {

  // If not dragging, send event to next responder

  if (!self.dragging)

  ```
  [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event];
  ```

  else

  ```
  [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
  ```

  }

  @end

And now in your UIViewController

// Create object for scroll view

AppScrollView* scrollView;

Comment: Mangesh, this may be a good solution but I'd `UIViewController` as my super class, so its not possible for me to make `UIScrollView` as my super class.

Comment: Please refer my updated answer, i am saying you to subclass for superview not for UIView