# How to resize the content of scrollview manually

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiscrollview

I need to resize the contents of horizontal scrollview by touching them. In my scrollview I have serial of images . I want to resize the image width only horizontally. The problem I am facing is that the scrollview is not detecting the UITouch events. Is there any way so that scrollview can detect the touch event. Or if there is some alternate way to get this task done.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` over scroll view to take touch event.

Comment: Thanks iPhoneDev.I know that , but want to confirm that are you sure UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged and stateBegin methods respond to tap gesture. I think they don't, but I am sure they do respond to Pan gesture. But I basically wanted to know if we can use UITouch event methods?

Comment: Hope this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397818/using-uitouch-inside-a-uiscrollview